# Where does the "Achyuta Anatha" shloka come from?

Tags: identification-request, shloka

> Achyuta anantha Govinda Namocharana Bheshajat
>
> Nashyanthi Sakala Roga Satyam Satyam vadamyaham
>
> Satyam Satyam Puna Satyam Udritya

Where does this shloka come from?